# Y Must be always positive in simplified expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been recently studiying an Algebra course online, and right now on a review test this expression must be simplified:
$$(-2x)^2(-y)^3$$
I distributed the exponent to the terms part and simplified it to
$$(4x^2)(-y^3)$$
My question here, it seems to be wrong on the top part simplification as the correct answer that the page graded me was 
$$(-4x^2)(+y^3)$$
So that means that the result I got before should be multiplied by $-1$ to get this answer, why is this? Isn't my answer exactly the same as this one? Is it part of a standard form to present this? Does the $y$ value must be always positive?

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Your way is fine, the second way, without parentheses $-4x²y³$, just looks nicer.

Comment: @GPerez Alright! Thanks alot! Was going crazy about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we have

> $(-2x)^2(-y)^3\ =\ (-2x)(-2x)(-y)(-y)(-y)\ =\ -4x^2y^3$

because there is an **odd** number (five) of sign switches altogether:
$$(-1)^5=(-1)(-1)(-1)(-1)(-1)=-1\,.$$

Anyway, the expressions $(-4x^2)(y^3)$ and $(4x^2)(-y^3)$ **coincide**, so both solutions are correct.

I think, it might be some kind of '*standard form*' as you guessed, namely that we prefer to put the '$-$' sign in front of the expression. (But this usage of parenthesis is rather unusual.)

Comment: Oh, thank you, I was trying to understand completely your past answer and could not find a reusable logic from it.. This makes much more sense now. Thank you.